# Creation of Team & Team User in one sql query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

[image: Team & Team User Database Tables]

I'm working with ASP.net & C# to create a sport league player transfer application. I'm currently working on the registration page and I want to do it in one go, i.e register a new team & a person of contact. My problem is that the Team_ID needs to go into the "Team_User" table to link the two tables together. Problem is I can't think of anything unique to both tables that I could set up a query for that would find the Team_ID in the "Team" table. Any ideas?

EDIT: Team_ID is auto-generated when a new team is added to the table.
I tried this and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
// define connection string and SQL query as strings
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Web_FussConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string query = "INSERT INTO Team (League_ID, Team_Name, Address_1, Stadium) values (@League_ID, @Team_Name, @Address_1, @Stadium) & SET @Team_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            string query1 = "INSERT INTO Team_User (Team_ID, First_Name, Job_Title, Telephone_Number, Email, Password_1, Last_Name) values (@Team_ID, @First_Name, @Job_Title, @Telephone_Number, @Email, @Password_1, @Last_Name)";
            // set up SqlConnection and SqlCommand in "using" blocks
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con))
            {
                // define and fill parameters
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@League_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["League_ID"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Team_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxAddress.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stadium", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxType.Text;
                int @Team_Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Team_ID"].Value);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@First_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxContactName.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Job_Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxTitle.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Telephone_Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBoxNumber.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxEmail.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Password_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxContactLastName;
                // open connection, execute Non Query, close connection
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @new_team_id int

-- insert into Team statement

set @new_team_id = (select scope_identity())

-- Insert new team id into Team_User
```

Read more about [scope_identity()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190315.aspx)

`@new_team_id` above is the value of Team ID that you just inserted.

**Edit**: Based on question edits.

Your code is not working because you have not used *output parameter*. You need to tell command object that `@Team_Id` is intended to be the output parameter whose value will be read in calling code. See how to do that here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net.aspx

**Suggestion**: I would still suggest with the other approach. You already have all the values (Team and Team_User entry details) available beforehand. Just have one procedure that accepts all the parameters and insert both records in one go. SP logic is already mentioned above.

Comment: FWIW this is the right answer but if you need multiple rows: `INSERT INTO Team ... OUTPUT inserted.Id, ... INTO TeamUser ...`

Comment: You could also use `select @new_team_id = scope_identity();` - no need for a `SET` and a `SELECT` - one is quite enough

Answer (score -1):

If you use Entity Framework it will look after the identifiers for you.

```
var team = new Team()
{
    -- populate fields
};
var user = new Team_User()
{
    -- populate fields
};
team.Team_Users.Add(user);
dbContext.Teams.Add(team);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```